# differentiation-chain rule- function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

Let $f\left ( x,y \right )$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Find a formula for $\frac{d}{dt}f\left ( t,t^{2} \right )\mid _{t=1}$ in terms of the partial derivatives: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left ( 1,1 \right )$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left ( 1,1 \right )$

I started to solve the problem as follows:
I applied the chain rule, and then I got: $$\frac{d}{dt}f\left ( t,t^{2} \right )=f_{1}\left ( t,t^{2} \right )\cdot 1+f_{2}\left ( t,t^{2} \right )\cdot 2t$$ 
and as $t\rightarrow 1$, I get: $$\frac{d}{dt}f\left ( t,t^{2} \right )\Big| _{t=1}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left ( 1,1 \right )+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left ( 1,1 \right ).$$

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your calculation of $\frac{d}{dt} f(t,t^2) \big|_{t=1}$ is correct.  But there is a typo in the question (I'm not saying you made it: perhaps it is made in wherever you saw the problem).

My guess is that either

- the references to the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ were supposed to be references to partial derivatives of $f$ at $(1,1)$, or
- the point of evaluation $t=1$ was supposed to be $t=0$.

Because, of course, as your general calculation shows, for any real $a$ the value of $\frac{d}{dt} f(t,t^2) \big|_{t=a}$ depends only on the values of the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(a,a^2)$, and not on the values of these functions at any other point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this to me. Yes, the original statement meant the partial derivatives at (1,1). I corrected the problem statement now.